# python not searching for file in the correct directory

Tags: python, file, directory

I'm trying to open a png file that is in the same directory as my script. Like anyone would do, I used os.path() but for some reason I got an error saying that the file doesn't exist. So I ran this code to show me where "path" was looking at.

```
from os import scandir

for i in scandir():
print(i.name)
```

To my surprise I get this as a result:

```
.android
.AndroidStudio3.5
.atom
.CocosCreator
.conda
.config
.dotnet
.idlerc
.ipython
.jupyter
.MCTranscodingSDK
.node_repl_history
.openshot_qt
.Origin
.PyCharmCE2019.3
.pylint.d
.QtWebEngineProcess
.templateengine
.thumbnails
.vscode
3D Objects
ansel
AppData
Apple
Application Data
Book1.xlsx
Calibre Library
Contacts
Cookies
Desktop
Documents
Downloads
Favorites
hello_world.xlsx
IntelGraphicsProfiles
Links
Local Settings
MicrosoftEdgeBackups
MostUsedSong.xlsx
Music
My Documents
NetHood
NTUSER.DAT
ntuser.dat.LOG1
ntuser.dat.LOG2
NTUSER.DAT{314cef2d-cea4-11ea-86b3-c37284cf2d52}.TxR.0.regtrans-ms
NTUSER.DAT{314cef2d-cea4-11ea-86b3-c37284cf2d52}.TxR.1.regtrans-ms
NTUSER.DAT{314cef2d-cea4-11ea-86b3-c37284cf2d52}.TxR.2.regtrans-ms
NTUSER.DAT{314cef2d-cea4-11ea-86b3-c37284cf2d52}.TxR.blf
NTUSER.DAT{314cef2e-cea4-11ea-86b3-c37284cf2d52}.TM.blf
NTUSER.DAT{314cef2e-cea4-11ea-86b3-c37284cf2d52}.TMContainer00000000000000000001.regtrans-ms
NTUSER.DAT{314cef2e-cea4-11ea-86b3-c37284cf2d52}.TMContainer00000000000000000002.regtrans-ms
ntuser.ini
OneDrive
Pictures
PrintHood
PycharmProjects
Recent
Saved Games
Searches
SendTo
Songs.xlsx
source
Start Menu
Templates
Videos
```

This means that python is looking at the directory where it is installed and not at the directory where my file is at. Is this a default option, and if it is how can I change it to the folder where my project is? Also, I can't use absolute path because I will send this folder to someone else and they won't have the same file structure as I do.

Comment: Default is current folder where you launch your script

Comment: you can use os.cwd to get the current dir. and then build the suitable path.

Comment: @Tarik Then why am I getting python's root folder?

Comment: Assuming you are at the command prompt at the folder where your script is located, then issue `python your script.py` you will get the stuff under your folder.

Comment: @Tarik I'm using VS Code to run the script

Comment: I think you can specify the current folder via project settings.